# UT005023: Exception handling request java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: AbstractSerializer: method <init>()V not found

Tags: maven, soap, jboss, wildfly

I'm migrating a SOAP web service project from tomcat to jboss. The firsts problems I faced were solved by dependencies. Now I can send a request from SoapUI but the response is an error. I'm sure that the error cause is some of the dependencies I added (I'm a newbie in spring/jboss things).

Here is the pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>webservices</artifactId>
    <version>5.5.6</version>

<!--    <properties> -->
<!--        <spring.version>3.2.1.RELEASE</spring.version> -->
<!--        <spring.sec.version>3.1.4.RELEASE</spring.sec.version> -->
<!--    </properties> -->
    

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>   
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> 
                <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId> 
                <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId> 
                <version>1.6.0</version> 
            </dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.wss4j/wss4j-ws-security-dom -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j-ws-security-dom</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.wss4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.0</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.ws.security/wss4j -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.ws.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>wss4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.6.19</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xml.security/xml-security -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.santuario/xmlsec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.0</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xml.security/xml-security -->






        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.19.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.security/spring-security-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.19.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-webmvc -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxws</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.7.4</version> -->
                <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-transports-http-jetty</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-security</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-ws-policy</artifactId>
<!--            <version>2.7.4</version> -->
            <version>3.2.0</version>
        </dependency>


<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-orm -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>${spring.version}</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles</groupId> <artifactId>org.apache.servicemix.bundles.cxf-2.0.5</artifactId> 
            <version>4.0-m1</version> </dependency -->

        <!-- dependency> <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId> 
            <version>1.5.6</version> </dependency -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>xalan</groupId>
            <artifactId>xalan</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-web -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.29.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>




<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>4.0.1.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId> 
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-entitymanager -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.persistence-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.bytebuddy</groupId>
    <artifactId>byte-buddy</artifactId>
    <version>1.10.10</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.22.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.2.Final</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
    <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.5.3</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.oracle.database.jdbc/ojdbc6 -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.oracle.database.jdbc</groupId>
    <artifactId>ojdbc6</artifactId>
    <version>11.2.0.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
       <scope>provided</scope>
       <version>9.0.39</version>
</dependency>
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>4.0.1.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-commons-annotations</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.2.0.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-jmx</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>3.5.6-Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->
<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>4.2.0.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-tools</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>4.0.0-CR1</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>hibernate-c3p0</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>4.0.1.Final</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.xerces</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
        </dependency>

<!--        <dependency> -->
<!--            <groupId>mysql</groupId> -->
<!--            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId> -->
<!--            <version>5.1.25</version> -->
<!--        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>sgitws</finalName>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                <version>2.3.1</version> -->
<!--                <configuration> -->
<!--                    <source>1.6</source> -->
<!--                    <target>1.6</target> -->
<!--                </configuration> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.4</version> -->
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
<!--                <version>2.4</version> -->
                <version>3.3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                    <warName>sgitws</warName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <groupId>es.gtd.sgit</groupId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
</project>
```

And here's the error trace

```
ERROR [io.undertow.request] UT005023: Exception handling request to /sgitws/services/filelogserver: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.xml.security.encryption.AbstractSerializer: method <init>()V not found
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.StaxSerializer.<init>(StaxSerializer.java:60) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessageInternal(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:204) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:175) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.ws.security.wss4j.WSS4JInInterceptor.handleMessage(WSS4JInInterceptor.java:86) [cxf-rt-ws-security-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:308) [cxf-core-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121) [cxf-core-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:267) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:234) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:208) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:160) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:191) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:301) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:220) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:523) [jboss-servlet-api_4.0_spec-2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.0.Final-redhat-00001]
    at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:276) [cxf-rt-transports-http-3.2.0.jar:3.2.0]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:74) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletChain$1.handleRequest(ServletChain.java:68) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.RedirectDirHandler.handleRequest(RedirectDirHandler.java:68) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:132) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.GlobalRequestControllerHandler.handleRequest(GlobalRequestControllerHandler.java:68)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:269) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:133) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:130) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(SecurityContextThreadSetupAction.java:105)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService$UndertowThreadSetupAction.lambda$create$0(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:1504)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:249) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:78) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:99) [undertow-servlet-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:376) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:830) [undertow-core-2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001.jar:2.0.28.SP1-redhat-00001]
    at org.jboss.threads.ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.run(ContextClassLoaderSavingRunnable.java:35)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor.safeRun(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1982)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.doRunTask(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1486)
    at org.jboss.threads.EnhancedQueueExecutor$ThreadBody.run(EnhancedQueueExecutor.java:1377)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [rt.jar:1.8.0_272]
```

I have no idea about what dependencies are causing this problem, any idea for checking it?.
Thanks.